# CS50 - Finance (/buy)

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a question regarding a problem set I need to solve (webpage using HTML and Flask). I managed to implement my code correctly without any syntax errors, but have been stuck in this error for very long now...Which results in a Error 500 whenever I try to use the "POST" method on the selected page.

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO history(Symbol, Amount, Price, Action, user_id, datetime) VALUES(:symbol, :amount, :price, :action, :uid ,:date)",
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol"),
        amount = number_of_shares,
        price= buy["price"],
        action="BOUGHT",
        uid=session["user_id"],
        date=datetime.datetime.now())
```

This is the SQLITE3 insertion I want to do, in a table named history.

Here is the information regarding the history table:

```
        Column #    Field       Type      Not NULL    Default Value   Primary Key
          0     Transaction ID  integer   Yes           None           Yes
          1         Symbol      text      No            None           No
          2         Amount      integer   No            None           No
          3         Price       numeric   No            None           No
          4         Action      text      No            None           No
          5         user_id     INTEGER   No            None           No
          6         datetime    datetime  No            None           No
```

I simply cannot figure out why this data cannot be inserted inside of the SQL table, the error message I keep getting in the temrinal is :

```
DEBUG:cs50:INSERT INTO history(Symbol, Amount, Price, Action, user_id, datetime) VALUES('AAPL', 3, 125.065, 'BOUGHT', 3 '2020-10-13 13:30:39')
```

If anyone has any idea what it could be, is it the types...? Thanks a lot!

Comment: EDIT: I just saw I forgot the comma between both placeholders :uid and :date, but that isn't the error

Comment: Have you tried wrapping column names in backticks in case one of the column names is being interpreted as a keyword? Something like ```INSERT INTO history(`Symbol`, `Amount`, `Price`, `Action`, `user_id`, `datetime`) VALUES('AAPL', 3, 125.065, 'BOUGHT', 3 '2020-10-13 13:30:39')```

Comment: Yeah, that didn't do it either.. thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma in your first line.

It should be:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO history(Symbol, Amount, Price, Action, user_id, datetime) VALUES(:symbol, :amount, :price, :action, :uid, :date)"
```

See if it works now!

Comment: Doesn't work, I saw that I forgot the comma between both placeholders yet the error 500 message still appears and points to that line... Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to help, but here was my code for the `buy` function when I did CS50 last year:

```
def buy():
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))
        shares = request.form.get("shares")
        
        #Check if symbol exists
        if data == None:
            return apology("invalid symbol", 400)
            
        #Check if shares entered is an integer
        try:
            shares = int(shares)
        except:
            return apology("shares must be a positive integer")
        
        #Check if shares entered > 0
        if shares <= 0:
            return apology("shares must be greater than 0", 400)
            
        #Check how much cash user has
        user = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])
        current_cash = user[0]["cash"]
        
        #Calculate amount required to buy shares
        price = data["price"] * shares
        
        #Check if user has enough money
        if price > current_cash:
            return apology("not enough money", 400)
        
        #Subtract price from user's cash
        current_cash = current_cash - price
        
        #Insert new cash into users database
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = :current_cash WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=session["user_id"], current_cash=current_cash)
        
        #Insert transaction into transactions database
        db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, name, shares, price) VALUES(:user_id, :symbol, :name, :shares, :price)", 
                   user_id=session["user_id"], 
                   symbol=request.form.get("symbol"),
                   name=lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))['name'],
                   shares=shares,
                   price=data["price"])
        
        flash("Bought!")
        
        return redirect("/")
    
    else:
        return render_template("buy.html")
```

Comment: It's not the best code, and there are differences in our variable and datebase names - but maybe just try looking through my code and maybe try to spot an error? Hope this helps!